# Can`t make HTTP request on physical android device using Capacitor

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I dont understand why HTTP requests fail with 404 error when i start app on physical android device, but it works correct when i`m testing my app using web browser. With requests to https there are no problems.

I`ve tried to use capacitor-http instead axios, but it doesnt help.

```
function getBaseUrl(): string {
  const personStore = usePersonStore();
  return personStore.selectedMedInst.baseURL;
}

export async function allDeps(): Promise<ReceptionDTO[] | undefined> {
  return (await Http.get({url: `${getBaseUrl()}/receptions`})).data



  // const url = `${getBaseUrl()}/receptions`;
  // const result = await axios.get<ReceptionDTO[]>(url);
  // return result.data;
}

export async function allSpecs(): Promise<SpecialityDTO[] | undefined> {
  const url = `${getBaseUrl()}/allspecs`;
  const result = await axios.get<SpecialityDTO[]>(url);
  return result.data;
}
```

And baseUrl i get from another pinia store (I use vue for my PWA). So, there is one of my base URL's:

```
http://46.175.215.101:8089/IMSToWebProxyNew
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you use to build and make the http request. Also check logcat for any errors/exceptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found a solution. To AndroidManifest i added this one -
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and all works fine.